# Azure Queue GetMessage Conditionally

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-worker-roles, azure-storage-queues, job-queue

We have multiple job messages being queued to cloud storage queue. The worker roles `GetMessage()` from respective Job Queues (We have multiple queues) and process them.

We are trying to create multiple workers process messages from same queue using dequeue visibility and instance identifiers however for these workers to `GetMessage()` I am not able to find a way to conditionally filter job messages that only this Worker is allotted to process.

For example, If Worker A is looking for JobMessages that has `WorkerName='WorkerA'` as one of its property or parameter, instead of using `JobQueue.GetMessage()` and then reading through every message to know if `WorkerName='WorkerA'` is there a way I can filter JobQueue to get Only Messages that has WorkerName = 'WorkerA'?

Comment: I figured out that GetMessage/ QueueMessage is not queryable. The option was to deploy multiple workers to look at multiple queues and queue Lease Coordinator to know if the jobmessage is already picked up or not. Now we have more queues which doesn't look very neat however this is the best approach we could come up with.

Comment: wow, can you please post an answer with the solution? so it can help others.